# Component is not receiving current, but previous input values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have two components to represent a list of articles and a filtering form. Every time any form field is changed, I need to send a HTTP request including the selected filters.

I have the following code for the `SearchForm`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

const SearchForm = ({ onFormChange }) => (
  <form>
    <Field component='select' name='status' onChange={onFormChange}>
      <option>All</option>
      <option value='published'>Published</option>
      <option value='draft'>Draft</option>
    </Field>

    <Field
      component='input'
      type='text'
      placeholder='Containing'
      onChange={onFormChange}
    />
  </form>
);

export default reduxForm({ form: 'myCustomForm' })(SearchForm);
```

And the following for the `PostsList`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchForm from './SearchForm';
import { dispatch } from 'redux'; 

class PostsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    this.onFormChange = this.onFormChange.bind(this);
  }

  onFormChange() {
    // Here I need to make the HTTP Call.
    console.info(this.props.myCustomForm.values);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.actions.fetchArticles();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm onFormChange={this.onFormChange} />            

        <ul>
          { this.props.articles.map((article) => (<li>{article.title}</li>)) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  myCustomForm: state.form.myCustomForm
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: {
    fetchArticles: dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_ARTICLES' })
  }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsList);
```

Though there is nothing going wrong with the rendering itself, something very awkful is happending  with the `myCustomForm.values` prop when I change the form.

When I do that for the first time, the `console.log(this.props.myCustomForm.values)` call returns `undefined`, and the next calls return the previous value.

For example:

1. I load the page and select the `draft` option. `undefined` is printed.
2. I select published. `{ status: 'draft' }` is printed.
3. I select `draft` again...  `{ status: 'published' }` is printed.

I inspected the redux store and the componend props. Both change according  to the form interaction. But my function is returning the previous, not the new value sent by `onChange`.

This is clearly a problem with my code, most probably with the way I'm passing the function from parent to child component.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your function. What I think is happening is that first time you select the option your callback is fired and is console logging **current** state for `myCustomForm.values` **which haven't been yet changed** by redux-form. So when the select changes:

1. your callback is fired...
2. ...then redux-form is updating the state.

So. when your callback is making console.log it's printing not yet updated store.

do this, and you will see it's true:

```
  onFormChange(e) {
    // Here I need to make the HTTP Call.
    console.info(e.currentTarget.value);
  }
```

**EDIT**

My first question would be, do you really need to store this value in redux and use `redux-form`? It's a simple case, and you get current value in a way I showed you above.

However, if that's not the case, the callback is not required here, you just need to detect in your connected component (PostsList) that values have been changed in a form. You can achieve it with [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) hook.

```
class PostsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // you should pass props to parent constructor
    this.onFormChange = this.onFormChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if(this.props.myCustomForm.values !== nextProps.myCustomForm.values) {
         // do your ajax here....
     }
  }

  componentWillMount(nextProps) {
    this.props.actions.fetchArticles();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm />            

        <ul>
          { this.props.articles.map((article) => (<li>{article.title}</li>)) }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is true... So I have another problem now lol
Is it possible to await for the store update?

Comment: Thank you so much @Tomasz! Well, this is only a "test drive" with redux form... Your code worked for me. Thank you again!